# CSS animationend EventListener Firing Repeatedly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addeventlistener

I am trying to simulate a collision detection by firing an event if all of the following conditions are present:

1. Up arrow key is down
2. The jump animation (assigned with cycleUp class) has ended
3. The user has left scrolled past a certain amount of pixels

The issue is that the eventListener is rapidly firing. I tried using a debounce function, but it only delayed the rapid fire.

**Javascript/Jquery**

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.which == '39') {
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleR");
                }   
                else if (e.which == '37'){
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleL");
                }
                else if (e.which == '38'){
                    $('#mainSprite').attr("class","cycleUp");

                    document.getElementById("mainSprite").addEventListener("animationend", function(){

                        var pos = $(document).scrollLeft();

                        if( pos >= 25 ){
                                alert("Jump");
                            }

                    }, false);

                }

                else {
                    $('#mainSprite').removeClass("cycleR");
                }
            });


$(this).keyup(function(){
        $('#mainSprite').removeClass();
});
```

[Here is a link to the site where I am trying to implement the code.](http://mariahweathersby.com) The little character will hop up and "hit" a marker to trigger an event. Please note, user will need to be able to scroll to multiple locations down the page and still have the event listener fire (aka "collide" with multiple objects).It essentially works like GPS. If the user has scrolled to the x-coordinate, and the animation has placed the character at the y-coordinate, fire an event.

Comment: Instead of debounce, throttle?

Comment: I think the event names are different for different browsers. That might be the problem: `webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On every keydown where `e.which == 38`, you are adding yet another event listener for `animationend`.  That means after a few keys, you will have multiple listeners and thus your callback will be called multiple times.

You have to either add the eventListener only once ever or you have to remove the event listener after it fires.

If using jQuery, you can use the `.one()` method of installing the event handler so that it will be automatically removed after it fires.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my issue. The user will need to be able to scroll to multiple locations down the page and still have the event listener fire (aka "collide" with multiple objects). This solution removes it completely after the initial fire. Also, when I tried removeEventListener, the function continued the rapid fire.

Comment: @MariahWeathersby - your comment doesn't make sense.  Your are adding a new event listener on every single key down.  That's just wrong because they will just accumulate until you have hundreds of them installed so every event, you will get hundreds of event handler callbacks.  There is no way that is the correct way to solve your problem. You don't show the code that initiates the animation so I feel like you're only showing half the problem.  When I tried to go look at your actual page, the `addEventListener()` wasn't even in the code that was in the page so I couldn't debug anything.

Comment: Hey, you were right about adding the event listener. It was not the .one() solution, but your other suggestion. I am going to update my live site and repost soon. I am a fairly new developer, so I didn't understand what you meant initially, but after some trial and error, it worked.